# Could not execute jacoco on jenkins

Tags: ant, jenkins, code-coverage, sonarqube, jacoco

When i am trying to gt sonar code coverage of my project through jenkins, i am getting the following error:
    Could not load definitions from resource org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

but when i am executing it through eclipse it does not show any error. code is same in both case and i have checked that in case of jenkins jacocoant.jar is included.

here is my code:

```
<taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
    <classpath path="../monet-main/lib/dev/sonar/jacocoant.jar" />
</taskdef>


<property name="sonar.tests" value="test" />
<property name="sonar.dynamicAnalysis" value="reuseReports" />
<property name="sonar.surefire.reportsPath" value="output/site/jacoco" />
<property name="sonar.java.coveragePlugin" value="jacoco" />
<property name="sonar.jacoco.reportPath" value="output/jacoco.exec" />

<target name="test">
    <mkdir dir="output/report/junit" />
    <javac debug="true" includeantruntime="false" nowarn="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" 
                encoding="UTF-8" source="1.6" target="1.6" srcdir="test">
        <classpath refid="monet-service.classpath" />
    </javac>
    <jacoco:coverage destfile="${result.exec.file}">

        <junit haltonfailure="yes" fork="true">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="monet-service.classpath" />
                <pathelement path="bin" />
            </classpath>
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
            <formatter type="xml" />
            <batchtest fork="yes" todir="output/report/junit">
                <fileset dir="test">
                    <include name="**/CommonTest.java" />
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </jacoco:coverage>
</target>

<target name="testReport" depends="test">
    <!--  Step 3: Create coverage report  -->
    <jacoco:report>
        <executiondata>
            <file file="${result.exec.file}" />
        </executiondata>
        <!--  the class files and optional source files ...  -->
        <structure name="JaCoCo Ant Example">
            <classfiles>
                <fileset dir="${result.dir}" />
            </classfiles>
            <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
                <fileset dir="${src.dir}" />
            </sourcefiles>
        </structure>
        <!--  to produce reports in different formats.  -->
        <html destdir="${result.report.dir}" />
        <csv destfile="${result.report.dir}/report.csv" />
        <xml destfile="${result.report.dir}/report.xml" />
    </jacoco:report>
</target>

<!-- Define the SonarQube target -->
<target name="sonar" depends="testReport">
    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
        <!-- Update the following line, or put the "sonar-ant-task-*.jar" file in your "$HOME/.ant/lib" folder -->
        <classpath path="../monet-main/lib/dev/sonar/sonar-ant-task-2.2.jar" />
    </taskdef>

    <!-- Execute the SonarQube analysis -->
    <sonar:sonar/>
</target>
```

Is there any problem..

Comment: You are using a relative path to your jacocoant.jar. What is the basedir attribute of your project and how does the directory structure look like? In Eclipse you can override the basedir, so this may change the default behavior of ant on the command line.

Comment: I think you realy need to show us the directory layout, where your build.xml lies and what the related paths are there, otherwise there is litte to no hope to help you. You may just compare your basedir to the working dir of the eclipse external tool configuration, otherwise no idea.

Comment: |--src
|--test
|--output/jacoco.exec
|--build.xml

Where |-- is current directory

Comment: Without many more informations i can't give any more advice than this: try to define the `<property name="jacoco.jar" location="../monet-main/lib/dev/sonar/jacocoant.jar" />` in the classpath. You can output this property to see if the path is correct (due to using the location instead of value). If the jar path is ok, then you have another problem then that. Did you check the eclipse external tool configuration? Do you run the script in the eclipse jre or a external one? * Did you check the working directory?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Yes. acyually problems were wirh the Test cases.. they are pld legacy code.. they are loading every test case into memory.